# How to implement multiprocessing in my BeautifulSoup WebScraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I made a web **scraper** with Python and BeautifulSoup lib and it works fine, only thing is that its very slow. So now, I want to implement some multiprocessing so that I can speed it up, but I do not know how.

My code is from two pars.
First part is **scraping** website so that I can generate urls that I want to scrape further, and appending those urls in list. First part looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta
from multiprocessing import Pool

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

links = [["Cross-Country", "https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/cross-country/cup-standings.html", "?sectorcode=CC&seasoncode={}&cupcode={}&disciplinecode=ALL&gendercode={}&nationcode="],
         ["Ski Jumping", "https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/ski-jumping/cup-standings.html", ""],
         ["Nordic Combined", "https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/nordic-combined/cup-standings.html", ""],
         ["Alpine", "https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/alpine-skiing/cup-standings.html", ""]]

# FOR LOOP FOR GENERATING URLS FOR SCRAPING

all_urls = []
for link in links[:1]:
    
    response = requests.get(link[1], headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    discipline = link[0]
    print(discipline)

    season_list = []
    competition_list = []
    gender_list = ["M", "L"]

    
    all_seasons = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "select select_size_medium")[0].find_all("option")
    for season in all_seasons:
        season_list.append(season.text)

    all_competitions = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "select select_size_medium")[1].find_all("option")
    for competition in all_competitions:
        competition_list.append([competition["value"], competition.text])


    for gender in gender_list:
        for competition in competition_list[:1]:
            for season in season_list[:2]:

                url = link[1] + link[2].format(season, competition[0], gender)
                all_urls.append([discipline, season, competition[1], gender, url])
                
                print(discipline, season, competition[1], gender, url)
                print()

print(len(all_urls))
```

You this first part is generating more than 4500 links, but I added some index limitations so that it only generate 8 links. This is second part of code, its a function that is basically a for loop that goes url by url and does scraping specific data. Second part:

```
# FUNCTION FOR SCRAPING
def parse():
    for url in all_urls:

        response = requests.get(url[4], headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        all_skier_names = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "g-xs-10 g-sm-9 g-md-4 g-lg-4 justify-left bold align-xs-top")
        all_countries = soup.find_all("span", class_ = "country__name-short")

        
        discipline = url[0]
        season = url[1]
        competition = url[2]
        gender = url[3]

        
        for name, country in zip(all_skier_names , all_countries):

            skier_name = name.text.strip().title()
            country = country.text.strip()
            
            print(discipline, "|", season, "|", competition, "|", gender, "|", country, "|", skier_name)

        print()

parse()
```

I have read some documentation that my multiprocessing part should look like this:

```
p = Pool(10)  # Pool tells how many at a time
records = p.map(parse, all_urls)
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

But I ran this and I waited 30 minutes, and nothing happened.
What am I doing wrong, how can I implement multiprocessing with pool, so that I can scrape 10 or more urls at the same time?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59086617/python-multiprocessing-on-list-of-dictionaries

Comment: Sorry, but that does not help me

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ and __scraping__ not scrapper or scrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's simple implementation with `multiprocessing.Pool`. Note, I used [`tqdm`](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) module to show nice progress bar (It's useful to see what's current progress in long running programs):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tqdm

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

def parse(url):
    response = requests.get(url[4], headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    all_skier_names = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "g-xs-10 g-sm-9 g-md-4 g-lg-4 justify-left bold align-xs-top")
    all_countries = soup.find_all("span", class_ = "country__name-short")

    discipline = url[0]
    season = url[1]
    competition = url[2]
    gender = url[3]

    out = []
    for name, country in zip(all_skier_names , all_countries):
        skier_name = name.text.strip().title()
        country = country.text.strip()
        out.append([discipline, season,  competition,  gender,  country,  skier_name])

    return out

# here I hard-coded all_urls:
all_urls = [['Cross-Country', '2020', 'World Cup', 'M', 'https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/cross-country/cup-standings.html?sectorcode=CC&seasoncode=2020&cupcode=WC&disciplinecode=ALL&gendercode=M&nationcode='], ['Cross-Country', '2020', 'World Cup', 'L', 'https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/cross-country/cup-standings.html?sectorcode=CC&seasoncode=2020&cupcode=WC&disciplinecode=ALL&gendercode=L&nationcode='], ['Ski Jumping', '2020', 'World Cup', 'M', 'https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/ski-jumping/cup-standings.html'], ['Ski Jumping', '2020', 'World Cup', 'L', 'https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/ski-jumping/cup-standings.html'], ['Nordic Combined', '2020', 'World Cup', 'M', 'https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/nordic-combined/cup-standings.html'], ['Nordic Combined', '2020', 'World Cup', 'L', 'https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/nordic-combined/cup-standings.html'], ['Alpine', '2020', 'World Cup', 'M', 'https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/alpine-skiing/cup-standings.html'], ['Alpine', '2020', 'World Cup', 'L', 'https://www.fis-ski.com/DB/alpine-skiing/cup-standings.html']]

with Pool(processes=2) as pool, tqdm.tqdm(total=len(all_urls)) as pbar: # create Pool of processes (only 2 in this example) and tqdm Progress bar
    all_data = []                                                       # into this list I will store the urls returned from parse() function
    for data in pool.imap_unordered(parse, all_urls):                   # send urls from all_urls list to parse() function (it will be done concurently in process pool). The results returned will be unordered (returned when they are available, without waiting for other processes)
        all_data.extend(data)                                           # update all_data list
        pbar.update()                                                   # update progress bar

# Note:
# this for-loop will have 8 iterations (because all_urls has 8 links)

# print(all_data) # <-- this is your data
```

Comment: I have run your code, I have 4 links, and it has been more than 10 minutes and its still 0% on the progress bar, and it takes around 20-30 seconds for one link if I'm not doing multiprocessing. i have also run  the `print(all_data)` at the end of the code but Its not printing anything.

Comment: Do you think that problem can be with indexing ( url[0], url[1],  url[2], url[3] url[4]) ?
I mean, now is around 30 minutes, my code is still running, and its still 0% and nothing is printed on the sceen

Comment: @taga Did you copy *exactly* the same code as I have in answer? Because It takes about 5 seconds in my machine and printing `len(all_data)` gives me `640`

Comment: Everything is the same, I just run my first part of code so that I get all_urls list

Comment: @taga Try it first with hard-coded list, as I have in answer. Then you can build from there...

Comment: I have tried with hard coded, its the same...im waiting ...but its still 0%

Comment: @taga Then the error is somewhere else. Try to put `timeout=3` in `response = requests.get(url[4], headers = headers, timeout=3)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206531/discussion-between-taga-and-andrej-kesely).

Comment: If I go to this loop: for data in pool.imap_unordered(parse, all_urls): and I print data, it does not shows me anything, the program does not goes into that loop at all. I think that the problem is with pool.imap_unordered(parse, all_urls)

Comment: @taga Put `print(url[4])` inside `def parse` function, before `requests.get(...)`.

Comment: The code does not goes into the function at all, i wrote a couple of print("...") statements all over the parse() function and it does not print anything.
it does not print when I do copy / paste with your code with hard-coded urls.
Its empty screen...nothing is printed

Comment: @taga Sorry, I cannot help you from here. In my computer the script works. Are you using Jupyter (maybe restart it will help)? The error from your description could be anywhere.

Comment: Im using Python's basic IDLE, that you get with instalation

Comment: @taga Maybe try to run the script (the exact I have in answer) from command line (not from IDLE or other editor)

Comment: Can you please add comment at the end of the code, where you put the for loop?
To explain that have you done (the last 5-6 lines of code)

Comment: @taga I added some comments at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted by @andrej-kesely work fine in Idle. Make sure the code has proper  spacing where is supposed to be

Comment: I do not know whats the problem. I have restarted my computer, I have ran the  code that Andrej posted and all I can see is:      
  0%|          | 0/8 [00:00<?, ?it/s]